# replace <title> on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code first to get current page slug:

```
var site_url = document.location.origin;
var slug = href.replace(site_url,'').substring(1).slice(0,-1);
```

after this I am using function to capitalize slug before put to

```
function CapitalFirstLetter(string)
{
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

var page_title = CapitalFirstLetter(slug);
```

And finally I am trying get it works on ajax success here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: href,
    success: function(data) {
       // update the page title
       document.title = page_title;
    }
});
```

But nothing happens

---

### Some solution I have for now

I make it works finally, since I am loading pages by ajax, I decided change title not on ajax success, but inside each page add script like this

```
$(function() {
    var loc = document.location.href;
    var site_url = document.location.origin;
    var slug = loc.replace(site_url,'').substring(1).slice(0,-1);
    var page_title = CapitalFirstLetter(slug);
    document.title = page_title;
});
```

works perfect now, but I am not sure if this good solution?

Comment: Is the success function getting called at all? How do you determine the title is not changing? Are there errors on the console? Could be the scope of the page_title-variable, can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: href,
    success: function(data) {
       // update the page title
   $("title").text(page_title);
    }
});
```

reference **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**

Comment: I have to admit - it's the first time I see something like `$("title")`

Comment: Why is this different from what he is doing? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_title.asp

Comment: you can check $("title").text(); in your console it works :)  in any url @RoyiNamir

Comment: ok i will check in IE @RoyiNamir in Mozilla and chrome it working on my end

Comment: Thanks Rituraj I've tried this one before, doesn't works for me. Any ideas why its happened, never tried change title before, and this is fully ajax wordpress theme, so I can't get current page title from header, because header always stays while pages content reloading

Comment: @RoyiNamir it is a 3 years old bug, should have been fixed, no?! (i didn't have tested it right now!)

Comment: please @RoyiNamir try at your end hope it will helpful please try it :)

Comment: @Rituraj I will try your solution later today, if I will fix my ajax success, for now it doesn't return anything to console, its weird since pages are loading fine on success

Comment: check that request goes or not is this your url is valid or not

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem is that your ajax call is completed before the page_title-variable is set, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5adTU/) as a demo.

You can fix it for example delaying the ajax call with

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: href,
      success: function(data) {
      // update the page title
       document.title = page_title;
      }
   });
}, 100);
```

Or using the ajax-functions beforesend to generate the title:

```
var page_title;

$.ajax({
      url: href,
      beforeSend: function() {
         page_title = ...  // generate the title...
      },
      success: function(data) {
      // update the page title
       document.title = page_title;
      }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks Esa, but the problem is not how to get slug, but how to put it after success ajax call. I've tried this $("title").text('test'); but not works for me

Comment: @Esa couldn't find any. don't know why it was remembered.

Comment: @Esa I am pretty sure your code should works, I will try later today, and if works I will accept your answer, thanks